# Why RTSP receive form is different between 2 cases

Tags: c++, live555

In `testRTSPClient.cpp`, I have 2 cases of receive result.

One is `DummySink::afterGettingFrame` and the other is `RTSPClient::handleResponseBytes`

I am getting different receieve form for these two.

I traced and debugged the code to know what is different, but failed.

one of the result

> Stream "rtsp://user@ip"; video/H264:  Received 19938
>   bytes.    Presentation time: 1567593326.272000 Stream "rtsp://user@ip//";
>   audio/PCMA:   Received 640 bytes. Presentation time: 1567593326.292000

the other result

> Received 2944 new bytes of response data. Received 2373 new bytes of
>   response data.

can anyone tell me why they are different?

Comment: result are not code... it's just output of terminal

Comment: It is difficult to guide, when we cannot see the code that produces the output.

Comment: @2tapgosu
What do you mean by receive result ?
handleResponseBytes is related to RTSP and afterGettingFrame is related to RTP.

Comment: @Durgesh i have 2 rtsp url, output of ./testProgs/testRTSPClient "rtsp://123,456,789,0" is Received 2968 new bytes of response data. and other url is /testProgs/testRTSPClient "rtsp://123.456.123.456/"
 that output is Stream "rtsp://123.456.123.456"; video/H264: Received 19938 bytes. Presentation time: 1567593326.272000